# Add Cisco VPN with login credentials an group name

Tags: networking, vpn

To log in to the server of a client of mine, I need to make a VPN connection. On Ubuntu I managed to do this quite easily following the steps as described here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/31100/how-do-i-install-the-cisco-vpn-client

Now, in elementary I can't seem to find the screen with corresponding to this one:

[image]

I have 4 credentials:
- gateway
- user name
- user password
- shared secret (group password)
- group name

On elementary OS, I only have options with certificates. How can I enable those other connection options? I can select the Cisco option:

[image]

But then my options are limited:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a account with NordVPN, they have linux users download ovpn files, which you can import.
See: https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/openvpn/

Does Cisco VPN provide something like that?

What weird is that I have less options in the "Choose a VPN Connection Type" dialog, I can only choose:

- OpenVPN
- Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP)
- Import a saved VPN configuration

Comment: I installed `openconnect` and `network-manager-openconnect-gnome` which brought the extra option.

Comment: Forgot to mention, unlike NordVPN, CiscoVPN is not a service.